# Unconditionally run a grunt task even if previous task failed, but maintain the failing exit code

Tags: gruntjs, protractor

Thought this was a general enough problem to share via a self answered question.

**General Scenario**

I have a primary task that might pass or fail, and I need to unconditionally run a seperate task as teardown.

I also need grunt to eventually exit using the pass/fail status from the  main task.

**Concrete scenario**

- I need to do some setup before running protractor.
- I need to do some teardown after running protractor.
- The setup and teardown are complex enough I am no longer comfortable performing these tasks in the protractor onPrepare and onCleanup blocks.
- I want to model these setup and teardown as seperate grunt tasks that run before and after my protractor job.
- I need the teardown to run every time, regardless of the pass/fail of protractor
- I need the final exit code of the grunt task to represent the pass/fail of protractor.

Assume I have a task called E2E (for E2E testing using protractor):

**Attempt1:**

```
grunt.registerTask('E2E', ['setupProtractorEnvironment', 'protractor', 'teardownProtractorEnvironment']);
```

if protractor fails then teardown is not run.

**Attempt2: add grunt-force-task**

I can solve part of this problem using the [grunt-force-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-force-task) as follows:

```
grunt.registerTask('E2E', ['setupProtractorEnvironment', 'force:protractor', 'teardownProtractorEnvironment']);
```

Now teardownProtractorEnvironment will always run, regardless of whether protractor fails or not, but the exit code is now always 0

**Attempt3 : use grunt this.requires()**

```
grunt.registerTask('exitWithProtractorStatus', function() {
  this.requires(['protractor']);
  return true;
})

grunt.registerTask('E2E', ['setupProtractorEnvironment', 'force:protractor', 'teardownProtractorEnvironment', 'exitWithProtractorStatus']);
```

Now when protractor fails, the teardown still runs, but the exit code is 3 (task error)

The final error code is important if I want to use this grunt task in CI and fail builds when the protractor E2E fails.

HTH !

Answer (score 1):

As shown in question **Attempt 3**, you can add a new task that use grunt's `this.requires()` to test the status of a previous task.

`this.requires` is documented here : http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.requires . Basically it will fail the current task unless all of the specified "required" tasks have already run and passed.

Comment: Thank you for this write up, it was very helpful even nearly 4 years later. One thing I would like to add is to make sure you use the right task name in this.requires(). I was using "jshint" when I should have been using "jshint:files"